# Delimit array with different strings

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, csv

I have a text file that contains 3 columns of useful data that I would like to be able to extract in python using numpy.  The file type is a *.nc and is **NOT** a netCDF4 filetype.  It is a standard file output type for CNC machines.  In my case it is sort of a CMM (coordinate measurement machine).  The format goes something like this:

X0.8523542Y0.0000000Z0.5312869

The X,Y, and Z are the coordinate axes on the machine.  My question is, can I delimit an array with multiple delimiters?  In this case: "X","Y", and "Z".

Comment: So you want to extract your X, Y, and Z coordinates?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: I would like my output to be 3 separate arrays of the X, Y, and Z coordinate.

Comment: Is the column width always the same?  `genfromtxt` allows you to specify widths as 'delimiter'.

Comment: Not sure, but I would want more robust code than counting on column widths.

Comment: Another approach is to run the file through a filer function that substitutes a conventional delimiter.  `genfromtxt` accepts input from anything that will feed it lines - a file, a list of strings, or function that massages file lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pandas

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

#Create a mock file
ncfile = StringIO("""X0.8523542Y0.0000000Z0.5312869
X0.7523542Y1.0000000Z0.5312869
X0.6523542Y2.0000000Z0.5312869
X0.5523542Y3.0000000Z0.5312869""")

df  = pd.read_csv(ncfile,header=None)

#Use regex with split to define delimiters as X, Y, Z.
df_out = df[0].str.split(r'X|Y|Z', expand=True)

df_out.set_axis(['index','X','Y','Z'], axis=1, inplace=False)
```

Output:

```
  index          X          Y          Z
0        0.8523542  0.0000000  0.5312869
1        0.7523542  1.0000000  0.5312869
2        0.6523542  2.0000000  0.5312869
3        0.5523542  3.0000000  0.5312869
```

Comment: Scott, this is good but I don't seem to be able to index over the output array.  I get an unhashable type: 'slice' error when I try to get the first column out df_out[:,0].

Comment: Okay, you were working with a pandas dataframe object.  You can use .iloc to index df_out.iloc[:,0] or you can convert to numpy array using df_out.values[:,0].

Comment: Scott, this may go beyond the scope of this thread, but is there a way I can convert these arrays to floats instead of strings?

Comment: Try `df_out.apply(pd.to_numeric)`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the Pandas solution provided by Scott.  For some reason I am not 100% clear on, I cannot simply convert the array from string to float with float(array).  I created an array of equal size and iterated over the size of the array, converting each individual element to a float and saving it to the other array.

Thanks all

Comment: `float` when given a string expects a string that is a valid representation of **one** number.  It can't convert multiple numbers, or strings with extra characters.

Answer (score 0):

Using the filter function that I suggested in a comment:

String sample (standin for file):

```
In [1]: txt = '''X0.8523542Y0.0000000Z0.5312869
   ...: X0.8523542Y0.0000000Z0.5312869
   ...: X0.8523542Y0.0000000Z0.5312869
   ...: X0.8523542Y0.0000000Z0.5312869'''
```

Basic genfromtxt use - getting strings:

```
In [3]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), dtype=None,encoding=None)
Out[3]: 
array(['X0.8523542Y0.0000000Z0.5312869', 'X0.8523542Y0.0000000Z0.5312869',
       'X0.8523542Y0.0000000Z0.5312869', 'X0.8523542Y0.0000000Z0.5312869'],
      dtype='<U30')
```

This array of strings could be split in the same spirit as the `pandas` answer.

Define a function to replace the delimiter characters in a line:

```
In [6]: def foo(aline):
   ...:     return aline.replace('X','').replace('Y',',').replace('Z',',')
```

`re` could be used for a prettier split.

Test it:

```
In [7]: foo('X0.8523542Y0.0000000Z0.5312869')
Out[7]: '0.8523542,0.0000000,0.5312869'
```

Use it in `genfromtxt`:

```
In [9]: np.genfromtxt((foo(aline) for aline in txt.splitlines()), dtype=float,delimiter=',')
Out[9]: 
array([[0.8523542, 0.       , 0.5312869],
       [0.8523542, 0.       , 0.5312869],
       [0.8523542, 0.       , 0.5312869],
       [0.8523542, 0.       , 0.5312869]])
```

With a file instead, the generator would something like:

```
(foo(aline) for aline in open(afile))
```